# InitialContext issue with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting the following error message:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:645)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:325)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
        at edu.neu.cs5200.Homework4.UserManager.getConnection(UserManager.java:31)
        at edu.neu.cs5200.Homework4.UserManager.createUser(UserManager.java:55)
        at edu.neu.cs5200.Homework4.UserManager.main(UserManager.java:95)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at edu.neu.cs5200.Homework4.UserManager.createUser(UserManager.java:58)
        at edu.neu.cs5200.Homework4.UserManager.main(UserManager.java:95)
```

within web.xml (within Web-INF folder)

I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Homework4</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <resource-ref>
        <description>Homework 4 MySQL Data Source</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/DBHomework4</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

Then, Within tomcat's context.xml I have this:

```
  <Resource name="jdbc/DBHomework4" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="root" password="root"
               driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/Homework4"/>
```

All this should be correct, yet I am still getting the InitialContext error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You're running your application directly from main(), and it should be run in an Servlet container (Tomcat) that will provide the context. You should deploy your application to Tomcat and call the UserManager from a Servlet.